# Python bokeh GMapPlot on Tab Pane widgets

Tags: python, google-maps, widget, bokeh

I want to create **2 GMapPlots** in the same plot (HTML) object **on separate Tab Panes**, but when I click **on my second tab** then no Google Map nor my little circles are displayed. The **whole area of the plot is grey** and the "Google" logo is displayed in the bottom-left corner, but there is no Map. My title of my tab-plots are change correctly when I click on the tabs, and the hover objects are displayed correctly on both plots.

I created the 2 plots in a for cycle using the same data source, so all the code is the same, expect the data values (GPS coordinates) that differ. I have a column that can only have 2 values that define the exact data source (the rows) of each plot. If I filter out the rows of my first plot in the line of for cycle code, then my "original second" plot appears correctly. So in this case I have only 1 tab, that has actually the "second" plot of my original 2-tab plot and it is displayed correctly in this case (without an other map on other tab).

So it looks like that GMapPlot can be used only for 1 plot in the same plot (HTML) object. Is it true?

1) Of course, if I make the separate bokeh HTML objects (without Tab Panes) then both Maps (and the circles) are displayed correctly.

2) If I create e.g. 2 bar charts in the same plot object (same HTML file) on separate Tab Panes then both charts are displayed correctly.

So does anybody know what the problem could be and how to solve it?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid as of Bokeh `0.12.10` this is still an [open known issue specific to GMap plots](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6934). You can watch that issue for updates.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I hope it will be fixed soon :)